# ERD design pro and contra

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, erd

I have one question regarding database design.

Here is the first example: 
[image: Database schema]

`User` may have a multiple `Websites`, and user can request specific resource for every of his websites. All requests are saved in `RequestForResource` table.

Now, if I want to see the name of an user who requested a resource, I have to join tables `RequestForResource` `Website` and table `User`.

To avoid this, I can make foreign key between `RequestForResource` and `User` table like it is demonstrated here:

[image: Schema 2]

Now, in order to get an user name, I have to join table `RequestForResource` and table `User` which is probably easier for SQL server, but at the other hand I have one foreign key more.

Which approach is better and (or) faster and why?

Comment: i think this question is better asked in dba. btw how do you link resources and websites? without this link it is not possible to satisfy the query. lots if ids in every table... are they all **needed**?

Comment: If you put UserID in RequestForResource, you might consider taking it OUT of Website.

Comment: @TabAlleman yep, but again, if I want all websites of the user, this relation is handy :)

Comment: You would be able to get that information from RequestForResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always duplicate information to gain execution speed. This is called: denormalisation. Yes, it will probably speed up the queries by lowering the required count of index seeks.

BUT

You have to write your code to make sure, that the data is consistent:
With the second design it is possible, to insert `Website.User_idUser` and a `RequestForResource.User_idUser` with different IDs for the same site! According to the design this is valid (but probably this will not satisfy your business rules).

Consider to update the foreign key constraint (or add a second one) which refers only to the Website table (`User_idUser`, `Website_idWebsite`) and remove the `User`-`RequestForResource` one.

Also consider to build a view to query your data with all the required info (probably with a clustered index).

Comment: So ususally how is this done, in real applications on the real systems? I don't want to hear as per theory (books) you should do it this way or this way. Is there some recommended way for specific situations?

Comment: The 'specific' part depends on lots of things (from the HW under the DB to business rules and decisions). Here are some questions: (yes in a real env, you should ask questions first): Do you really need this denormalisation now? Is this a real bottleneck, or just an attempt to prepare for everything? Can a view help? (test it!). A general rule: do not generate problems for solutions, and do not solve problems that are not exist. Solve existing problems. If this is one of them, sample queries, exec plans, index structure helps us to say something useful. Right now this is a theoretical question